# Understanding of example of subspacee

Tags: linear-algebra, learning

Let F be a field. Then, { (a,b) $\in$ F: $\alpha$a+$\beta$b=0} is a subspace of FxF for any $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\in$ F.

My question is that can be FxF is a subspace of f? If not, why?

Comment: The definition has an error in that it says $(a,b)\in F$ which does not make sense.

Comment: Do you know the notion of dimension of a vector space?

Comment: @Crostul I don't know yet.

Comment: Well, the idea is that $F$ has dimension 1, while $F \times F$ has dimension 2. The first is too small to contain the second, as much as a line cannot contain a plane. When you'll come to the notion of dimension (I'm sure you'll see it very soon), everything will become obvious.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks, I understood.

Answer (score 0):

First ask yourself is F×F a subset of F. And youll get the answer immediately